# Passenger stays in foreground when started from Vagrant

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, passenger, vagrant

In the console, I'm used to entering one of:

```
cd /vagrant/project/ && rvm passenger start -p80 -d --user vagrant -e vagrant
cd /vagrant/project/ && rvm passenger start -p80  --user vagrant -e vagrant &
```

And Passenger starts and gives me control again.

Now, using Vagrant, I want to make tests that will:

1. automatically start Passenger, then
2. do other stuffs.

But the script can't do anything else; it stays stucked in Passenger.

I'm using [ssh.execute](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb), which calls [ssh.shell_execute](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb):

```
shell_execute(???? , "cd /vagrant/project/ && rvmsudo passenger start -p80 -d --user vagrant -e vagrant" , false)
```

Does anyone have a solution?
Or does anyone have an idea where this problem is coming from?

---

Adn the end i've found a deerty hack, which make it working:

```
shell_execute(???? , "cd /vagrant/project/ && rvmsudo passenger start -p80 -d --user vagrant -e vagrant </dev/null &>/dev/null" , false)
```

But i don't really understand. stdin was not accessible anymore in the script. I'm curious so, does anyone know where does stdin pointed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it in forked process

```
fork {
  `your command`
}
```

Comment: I think i've tried it, and it didn't success yesterday. And i try to Thread and so on ...